# programming openssl over multi-core machine

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, openssl

I'm doing my first steps into the openssl lib and feel a bit lost

My machine is a multi-threaded (can share more if someone need the info ~ Xeon series) with linux OS

I want to run the lib a lock-less a possible .

after looking a bit inside `crypto/crypto.h`
mainly on this section :

```
# ifndef OPENSSL_NO_LOCKING
#  ifndef CRYPTO_w_lock
#   define CRYPTO_w_lock(type)     \
        CRYPTO_lock(CRYPTO_LOCK|CRYPTO_WRITE,type,__FILE__,__LINE__)
#   define CRYPTO_w_unlock(type)   \
        CRYPTO_lock(CRYPTO_UNLOCK|CRYPTO_WRITE,type,__FILE__,__LINE__)
#   define CRYPTO_r_lock(type)     \
        CRYPTO_lock(CRYPTO_LOCK|CRYPTO_READ,type,__FILE__,__LINE__)
#   define CRYPTO_r_unlock(type)   \
        CRYPTO_lock(CRYPTO_UNLOCK|CRYPTO_READ,type,__FILE__,__LINE__)
#   define CRYPTO_add(addr,amount,type)    \
        CRYPTO_add_lock(addr,amount,type,__FILE__,__LINE__)
#  endif
```

my question(s) to begin with is :

**EDIT : After discussion made in the comment section**

**(1)** Is it possible to run several instances of openSSL (per core ?) on my machine?meaning : are there are part of OpensSSL lib that must run once per OS ?

2)How much support do I have for multi-threaded lock-less programming without any changes to lib?

3)assuming I have all the CFLAGS set correctly (?)

where should I begin in manipulating the lib 
(meaning what components are created only once for entire machine that may increase performance if I make each tread run it's own instance)

Comment: Many hashing algorithms, for example, cannot be parallelized at all just because of their nature. So, multithreading may not be that helpful.

Comment: What are you trying to do with OpenSSL exactly?

Comment: @ForceBru , can you please expend on it ? How is it being implemented on large scale servers

Comment: @Sanchke Dellower security application

Comment: @LordTitiKaka, I think you shouldn't mess with this as such changes require relatively deep understanding of how OpenSSL works and, what's more, you may not get any significant speedup by tweaking this stuff. OpenSSL already uses assembly wherever possible for maximum execution speed.

Comment: @LordTitiKaka Well what functions are you going to be using? Because if you're doing things such as AES and RSA, then multi threading is very easy if not self explanatory.

Comment: Well when I think about it my main question is does the OpenSSL know to take burst of packets and handle packet concurrently , meaning , packets of data are relatively Independent

Comment: It doesn't have to. Bursts of padkets are handled by the network stack, not by OpenSSL. All OpenSSL sees is a TCP bye stream. Unclear what you're asking. Maybe you're looking for a hardware crypto accelerator?

Comment: @EJP My application is SSL-Proxy (you can call it Man In the Middle defense ~ like what AVAST does ... ) , so basically I have packets coming from the NIC(s) and I have to handle all flows inside the openSSL lib --> I have many packet to encrypt/decrypt so the bursts coming from the NIC needed to be handled , If you(you all) want I'll be happy to take it off-site